# Dimension of System.Object[*] C#

Tags: c#, excel, casting, vsto

I am converting an Excel VSTO addin from VB.NET to C#. I am struck with getting the dimension of the System.object[*] returned by the Application.Evaluate() function.

I get the error message below during the runtime when the function is called.

> Unable to cast object of type System.Object[*] to System.Object[].

Below are the original VB.NET code followed by the C# code. I had no issues with VB.NET code.

I tried to cast to Array, dynamic but of no use. Is there any alternative way to achieve my goal of getting the dimension of the Excel Application.Evaluate() function?

```
If GetDimension(xlapp.Application.Evaluate(FormulaString)) = 0 Then
    'The formula results in single value.
Else
     'The formula is Matrix Based. 
End If
```

Below is original VB.NET Sub function.

```
    Private Function GetDimension(MatResult As Object) As Integer
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim LoopCheck As Boolean = True
        Dim RankException As Integer
        Dim Dimension As Integer
        i = 0
        Do
          i += 1
          Try
              RankException = UBound(MatResult, i)
          Catch ex As Exception
              Dimension = i - 1
              LoopCheck = False
          End Try

       Loop Until Not LoopCheck

       Return Dimension 
   End Function
```

Below is the converted code in C#

```
if(GetDimension(xlapp.Application.Evaluate(FormulaString)) == 0)
    //The formula results in single value.
else
     //The formula is Matrix Based.
```

The converted function is below.

```
    public int GetDimension(object MatResult)
    {
        int i;
        bool LoopCheck = true;
        int RankException;

        if (MatResult.GetType() == typeof(double) || MatResult.GetType() == typeof(string))
            return 0;

        int Dimension = 0;
        Array CastedMat = (Array)MatResult;
        i = 0;
        do
        {
            i++;
            try
            {
                RankException = CastedMat.GetLength(i);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Dimension = i - 1;
                LoopCheck = false;
            }
        }
        while (LoopCheck);

        return Dimension;
    }
```

Comment: Is `getDimension()` really the same thing as `GetDimension()`?

Comment: You could do `Array CastedMat = MatResult as Array;` and then if `CastedMat` is null, it's not an array.

Comment: @itsme86 Its not helping. I really need to get the dimension of the Array in the case of `Application.Evaluation() returning object[*]`. Again, I have edited the function name to GetDimension.

Comment: @Raghu I try to understand your question, Do you want to convert an excel range to an array of cells or you already make that array but you do not know its dimension ,sorry for my misunderstanding

Comment: `Ubound` and `GetLength` work differently. `Ubound` uses 1-based indexes (which is why even though `i` is initialized to zero, the first check is actually against 1; the first line inside `Do` loop increments it) where as `GetLength` uses zero-based indexes. So your conversion is not correct. (start `i` at -1 or increment it after the fact). This won't necessarily fix your problem, just calling that out

Comment: And btw, `System.Object[*]` (note the `*`) indicates an array that has a non-zero lower bound. What line are you getting the exception on because you should be able to cast to `Array` just fine

Comment: @pinkfloydx33. The code fails at the entry point to the function. As you can see the local variable is declared as an object while the parameter of the calling function is system.object[*]

Comment: Thanks @itsme86, I am able to resolve the issue through the hint provided by you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve this issue through some hints provided above.
Below is the code which is working.

```
    public int GetDimension(object MatResult)
    {
         int MatrixRank;

        if (MatResult.GetType() == typeof(double) || MatResult.GetType() == typeof(string))
            return 0;

        Array CastedMat = MatResult as Array;
        MatrixRank = CastedMat.Rank;
        return MatrixRank;
    }
```